# Yahoo Finance news pubDate not accessable by ruby nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rss, nokogiri, yahoo-finance

I'm able to access Yahoo Finance news headlines *title*, but have a hard time **parsing *pubDate* so that I only look at say the last week's news and ignore anything older**.

```
require 'nokogiri'
sym = "1313.HK"
url = "https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=#{sym}&region=US&lang=en-US"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

titles = doc.css("title")
puts titles.length # works, comes back with 0-20
puts titles.text # works

pubDates = doc.css("pubDate")
puts pubDates.length #does NOT work, always 0
puts pubDates.text #does NOT work, always blank

keywordregex = "bad news"
nodes = doc.search('title') # search title tags only, for keywords
puts found_title = nodes.select{ |n| n.name=='title' && n.text =~ keywordregex } # TODO && pubDate > 7 days old
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with Nokogiri::XML, rss is really XML.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @pguardiario, switching from HTML to XML helps.

Answer (score 0):

`pubdate` node names in your XML source are lowercase.

```
 > doc.css("pubdate").length
 => 7
```